# axios get request returns an empty object nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am attempting to set up user authentication using Nuxt 3, JWT, and MongoDB as my database. The register endpoint is functioning correctly. However, when I use the login endpoint, it verifies the registered user, sends the access token to the frontend, and calls the user endpoint, but I'm receiving an empty object as a response. The expected result is to receive the user data.

server/api/login.ts

```
import { User } from '../../models/users'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import Joi from 'joi'
import { sendError, H3Event, setCookie } from "h3"
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'


// Compares a password with its hashed version and returns a boolean result
async function comparePassword(password: string, hashedPassword: string) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword);
}


export default defineEventHandler(async (event: H3Event) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  try {
    const body = await readBody(event)
    const {email, password} = body
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    
    if (!user) {
      return sendError(event, createError({ statusCode: 401, data: 'Invalid email or password' }))
    }
    const isPasswordValid = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
    
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return sendError(event, createError({ statusCode: 401, data: 'Invalid email or password' }))
    }

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user.id
      },
     config.secretKey,
      {
        expiresIn: '1800s'
      }
    )
  
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user.id
      },
      config.secretKey,
      {
        expiresIn: '1d'
      }
    )
    
    user.refresh_token = refreshToken
    await user.save()

    setCookie(event, 'refresh_token', refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true, maxAge: 24*60*60*1000})
    return { access_token: accessToken }
    
  } catch (error : any) {
    return { statusCode: error.statusCode, data: error.data}
  }
    
});
```

server/api/auth/user.ts file (Here is where the problem lies)

```
export default eventHandler( async (event) => {
  const user = event.context.user
  return {user }
})
```

composables/useAuth.ts

```
import { axiosInstance, axiosPrivateInstance } from "../utils/axios";
import {useAuthStore} from '../stores/auth'
import { watchEffect } from "vue";
import type { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

export function useApiPrivate(): AxiosInstance  {

  const authStore = useAuthStore()
  watchEffect(()=>{
    axiosPrivateInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        if(!config.headers["Authorization"]){
          config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${authStore.accessToken}`
        }
        return config
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    )
  
    axiosPrivateInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      response => response,
      async (error) => {
        const prevRequest = error?.config
        if((error?.response?.status === 403 || error?.response?.status === 401) && !prevRequest.sent){
          prevRequest.sent = true
          try {
            await authStore.refresh()
            prevRequest.headers["Authorization"] = authStore.accessToken
            return axiosPrivateInstance(prevRequest)
          } catch (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error)
          }
        }
  
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    )
  })

  return axiosPrivateInstance
}


export function useApi(){
  return axiosInstance
}
```

store/auth.ts

```
import {useApi, useApiPrivate} from "../composables/useApi"

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
  state: (): State => {
    return {
      user: {} as User,
      accessToken: "" as string,
      authReady: false as boolean
    }
  },

  getters: {
    userDetail: (state: State) => state.user,
    isAuthenticated: (state: State) => state.accessToken ? true : false
  },

  actions:{
    async attempt(){
      try {
        await this.refresh()
        await this.getUser()
      } catch (error) {
        return
      }
      return
    },


    async login(payload: LoginData){
      try {
        const {data} = await useApi().post(`/api/auth/login`, payload);
        this.accessToken = data.access_token
        await this.getUser()
        return data
      } catch (error: Error | any) {
        throw error.message
      }
    },

    async register(payload: RegisterData){
      try {
        const {data} = await useApi().post(`/api/auth/register`, payload);
        return data
      } catch (error: Error | any) {
        throw error.message
      }
    },

    async getUser(){
      try {
        const {data} = await useApiPrivate().get(`/api/auth/user`);
        console.log(data)
        this.user = data
        return data
      } catch (error: Error | any) {
        throw error.message
      }
    },

    async logout(){
      try {
        const {data} = await useApiPrivate().post(`/api/auth/logout`);
        this.accessToken = ""
        this.user = {} as User
        return data
      } catch (error: Error | any) {
        throw error.message
      }
    },

    async refresh(){
      try {
        const {data} = await useApi().post(`/api/auth/refreshToken`);
        this.accessToken = data.access_token
        return data
      } catch (error: Error | any) {
        throw error.message
      }
    }
  }
})
```